# Count rows, or keep int field for counting?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count, mysql-num-rows

When I want to find out how many shoes Alfred has, I always count the rows in the table "usershoes" where the userid matches Alfred's

But since I switched to PDO, and select row count is not simple or bulletproof/consistent, I'm reconsidering my methods

Maybe I should instead keep an int field "shoes" directly in table "users", keep number of shoes there, and then increase/decrease that number for that user along the way? Feels not right..

If anyone has a solid method for simple row counting on an **existing** select query, **without extra query**, let me know

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` to count rows in your `SELECT`statement

Comment: I tried that, some, but couldn't get it to work. SELECT COUNT (*), shoename, shoesize, shoecolor FROM usershoes.. and then what? fetchColumn?

Comment: Right now I'm at count($STH->fetchAll()); Not the best solution, but so far it works

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usershoes
    WHERE userid="theIdOfTheUser";
```

Comment: So you're suggesting making an separate query just for counting? And how do I output the number of rows with this?

Comment: Well if you need all the data anyway to display them. I would [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) in `PDO` and count the returned array which containts all the results with PHPs `count()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get count(fetchColumn()) or fetchColumn() to work correctly (outputted 1 when 0 was the real number)

So now I'm using this, and it works:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as numrows, shoecolor FROM usershoes WHERE userid = ?'
$STH = $conn->prepare($sql);
$STH->execute(array($someuseridvar));
```

And then:

```
$row = $STH->fetch();

if ($row['numrows'] > 0) {

    // at least one row was found, do something

}
```

Answer (score -1):

With MySQL, you can use FOUND_ROWS():

```
$db = new PDO(DSN...);
$db->setAttribute(array(PDO::MYSQL_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY=>TRUE));
$rs  = $db->query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 5,15');
$rs1 = $db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');
$rowCount = (int) $rs1->fetchColumn();
```

`$rowCount` will contain the total number of rows, not 15.

Taken from:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#83586

Comment: Yes. I just want to be absolutely sure it counts correctly, and flexible.. php.net: "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, SOME  databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Comment: You're quoting a comment for PDOStatement::rowCount. Notice that my code doesn't use it.